# Docker for windows "server misbehaving" Error while pulling image from a machine on different domain

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

My company has two different domains **a.com** and **b.com**. I have a private docker registry configured on a ubuntu server machine, on a.com with domain name **pregistry** having self signed certificate. I can push and pull images from that registry into a windows 10 machine (docker for windows using linux containers) on a.com where the certificate for pregistry is installed as trusted. However I tried pulling an image from a windows 10 machine (docker for windows using linux containers) on b.com (the certificate is installed here too) and I get the following error.

```
PS C:\> docker pull pregistry:5000/image:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://pregistry:5000/v2/: dial tcp: lookup dfyuserver on 192.168.65.1:53: server misbehaving
```

I researched a bit and found that most of the problems are due to proxies. However, I am not behind any proxy. Also I am able to ping the server machine from the machine on b.com and it pings successfully. I also changed the DNS settings in docker desktop(on machine on b.com) yet the problem persists.Any input or ideas about the problem or its possible solution is welcome.Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: No, I wan't able to solve it. I had to use the server machine from the same domain.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it turned out I accidentally had docker desktop in the wrong mode. I was pulling a windows container while in linux mode.